# Getting the maximum of price increase

Tags: sql

I'm having problems figuring out this
I need to find the item(s) having the greatest percentage of price increase.
This is my code :

```
    Select
  q.Grocery_Item,
  TO_CHAR(q.Price_IN_2000, '$90.00') price_in_2000,
  TO_CHAR(q.Estimated_Price_In_2025, '$90.00') price_in_2025,
  TO_CHAR(w.MY_OUTPUT,'9,990') || '%' as My_Output
From
  GROCERY_PRICES q,
  (SELECT
     GROCERY_ITEM,
     (((Estimated_Price_In_2025-Price_IN_2000)/Price_IN_2000)*100) as MY_OUTPUT
   FROM
     GROCERY_PRICES
  ) w
Where
  q.GROCERY_ITEM = w.GROCERY_ITEM  and w.my_output in (select max(w.my_output) from GROCERY_PRICES group by grocery_item)
GROUP BY
 w.MY_OUTPUT, q.GROCERY_ITEM,  q.Price_IN_2000, q.Estimated_Price_In_2025
```

My output is :

```
    GROCERY_ITEM                   PRICE_IN_2000 PRICE_IN_2025 MY_OUTPUT
------------------------------ ------------- ------------- ---------
B_001                            $0.80         $2.64          230%   
B_002                            $2.72         $7.36          171%   
M_004                            $2.70         $5.65          109%   
T_006                            $5.70         $6.65           17%   
R_003                            $4.00        $13.20          230%   
E_001                            $0.62         $1.78          187%   

 6 rows selected
```

which is  basically all the data in my table

what I need to get is :

```
GROCERY_ITEM                   PRICE_IN_2000 PRICE_IN_2025 MY_OUTPUT
------------------------------ ------------- ------------- ---------
B_001                            $0.80         $2.64          230%   
R_003                            $4.00        $13.20          230%
```

sorry new here, don't know how to format my question :(

thanks in advance.

Comment: Post some sample data into a sqlfiddle.

Comment: Which SQL DBMS are you using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
with price_delta as (
  select grocery_item, 
         price_in_2000, 
         ESTIMATED_PRICE_IN_2025, 
         ((ESTIMATED_PRICE_IN_2025 - Price_IN_2000)/Price_IN_2000)*100 as delta,
         rank() over (order by ((ESTIMATED_PRICE_IN_2025 - Price_IN_2000)/Price_IN_2000)*100 desc) as rnk
  from grocery_prices
)
select grocery_item, 
       price_in_2000, 
       ESTIMATED_PRICE_IN_2025,
       delta
from price_delta
where rnk = 1;
```

SQLFiddle (Oracle): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/43379/2

Comment: I'm using Oracle sql developer, the data used to create and populate the table : 

CREATE TABLE grocery_prices
( GROCERY_ITEM     VARCHAR2(30) PRIMARY KEY,
  PRICE_IN_2000     NUMBER(6, 2),
  ESTIMATED_PRICE_IN_2025    NUMBER(6, 2));

INSERT INTO grocery_prices VALUES('E_001',  0.62,  1.78);
INSERT INTO grocery_prices VALUES('B_001',  0.80,  2.64);
INSERT INTO grocery_prices VALUES('B_002',  2.72,  7.36);
INSERT INTO grocery_prices VALUES('M_004',  2.70,  5.65);
INSERT INTO grocery_prices VALUES('T_006',  5.70,  6.65);
INSERT INTO grocery_prices VALUES('R_003',  4.00, 13.20);
COMMIT;

Comment: @DuckStalker: I changed the SQLFiddle. Please do **not** post code as a comment. Edit your question.

Comment: thanks a lot, now i need to figure out how to display the record without the rnk column

Comment: @DuckStalker: simply replace the `*` with the columns you want to see. See my edit.

Comment: thanks a lot :), for some reason when i tried that earlier it gave me an error!, thanks again